# If the integral of $\frac{dQ}{T}$ over an engine cycle is less than 0 , then why is entropy of the universe always increasing?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, arrow-of-time

For a reversible process, we define $ dS= \frac{dQ}{T}$ , so, the integral being negative would suggest that the entropy of universe decreases with each cycle of the engine because the clasius inequality states this quantity is less than 0

Comment: If it's a cycle, it means that, at the end of the cycle, the working fluid returns to its original state, in which case its change in entropy is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The value of $\Delta S_{\text{sys}}$

You are confusing the entropy change of the system with the total entropy change. Now since the process is cyclic, the total entropy change for the system will be zero ($\Delta S_{\text{sys}}=0$). It does not matter whether the process is reversible or irreversible because entropy is a state function and depends only on the initial and the final states, which in this case are the same.

### What about $\Delta S_{\text{surr}}$?

Now, I would like to state the Clausius inequality more clearly:

$$\oint\frac{\delta Q_{\text{sys}}}{T_{\text{surr}}}≤0\tag{1}$$

As you can see, the temperature in the denominator is the temperature of the surroundings, not the system, and $\delta Q_{\text{sys}}$ is an inexact differential of the **heat given to the system**. Since the amount of heat given to the system will be equal to the amount of heat lost from the surroundings, thus

$$\delta Q_{\text{sys}}=-\delta Q_{\text{surr}}\tag{2}$$

So, now let's compute $\Delta S_{\text{surr}}$ (entropy change of the surroundings) for a cyclic process:

$$\Delta S_{\text{surr}}=\oint \frac{\delta Q_{\text{surr}}}{T_{\text{surr}}}\tag{3}$$

But using equation $(2)$, we can rewrite the above equation as:

$$\Delta S_{\text{surr}}=-\oint \frac{\delta Q_{\text{sys}}}{T_{\text{surr}}}\tag{4}$$

Now, using equation $(1)$, we can conclude that

$$\Delta S_{\text{surr}}=-\oint \frac{\delta Q_{\text{sys}}}{T_{\text{surr}}}≥0\Longrightarrow \Delta S_{\text{surr}}≥0\tag{5}$$

### Total entropy change

The total entropy change is given by

\begin{align}
\Delta S_{\text{total}}&=\underbrace{\Delta S_{\text{sys}}}_{=0}+\underbrace{\Delta S_{\text{surr}}}_{≥0}\\
\therefore \Delta S_{\text{total}}&≥0\tag{6}
\end{align}

Thus, as you can see, Clausius inequality also yields the fact that the total entropy of the universe must increase. Do note that the equality in the equation $(6)$ holds when the process is reversible.